# If / ifelse statement to hide 'h2' if no search results

Tags: php, html, if-statement

Can anybody help me on how I can stop an heading displaying if there are no search results?

The app generates palettes based on flickr images, at the minute I have a few else statements for validation that if there are no results from the flickr API etc, then a message will appear, as shown:

```
      // No results from Flickr
        } else {
            echo "<div class=\"errormsg\"> Uh oh... no results for that Hex. Why not try a keyword?</div>";
        }
    } else {
        // Error with the Flickr API
        echo "<div class=\"errormsg\"> Oh boy... there was an error with the API.</div>";
    }
} else {
    // No hex code entered
    echo "<div class=\"errormsg\"> Hey, it looks like you forgot to enter a hex code - Try again!</div>";
}
```

If there are results it will display a heading (#welcomeDiv) stating

> Displaying palettes for...

However, I only want this to display if there are results, I have tried:

```
else{
?>
<style type="text/css">#welcomeDiv{
display:none;
}</style>
<?php
}
```

## welcomeDiv that I want hidden

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { ?>
        <h2 id="welcomeDiv">Displaying palettes for <span class="hex">"<?php echo $_POST['hex'] ?>"</span></h2>

        <div id="results">
            <?php include 'assets/php/generate.php'; ?>
        </div><!--/results-->
    <?php } ?>
```

But this doesn't apply. Does anybody know why?

Here's [a link](http://scm.ulster.ac.uk/~B00553636/hexactly/app.php) to the project.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't mix your CSS going in and out of PHP, you don't need to do that. Just place your styles inside `<head></head>` and it will take care of itself.

Comment: I also don't see a `welcomeDiv` div ID, show it.

Comment: We need to see the whole PHP loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This edit could work.

```
// No results from Flickr
        } else {
?>
    <style type="text/css">#welcomeDiv{ display:none;}</style>
<?php
            echo "<div class=\"errormsg\"> Uh oh... no results for that Hex. Why not try a keyword?</div>";
        }
    } else {
        // Error with the Flickr API
        echo "<div class=\"errormsg\"> Oh boy... there was an error with the API.</div>";
    }
} else {
    // No hex code entered
    echo "<div class=\"errormsg\"> Hey, it looks like you forgot to enter a hex code - Try again!</div>";
}
```

I see you also have jquery referred in the link. You can use javascript to hide the heading.

```
// No results from Flickr
            } else {
    ?>
        <script>$('#welcomeDiv').hide();</script>
    <?php
                echo "<div class=\"errormsg\"> Uh oh... no results for that Hex. Why not try a keyword?</div>";
            }
        } else {
            // Error with the Flickr API
            echo "<div class=\"errormsg\"> Oh boy... there was an error with the API.</div>";
        }
    } else {
        // No hex code entered
        echo "<div class=\"errormsg\"> Hey, it looks like you forgot to enter a hex code - Try again!</div>";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, this doesn't seem to hide the div unfortunately

Comment: which one are you trying? Any errors on the console? (You can open console via Rt. click> Inspect element on google chrome)

Comment: The first answer, when I add a paragraph (to test it) within the first else, it shows, however the display:none on the #welcomeDiv doesn't apply

Comment: Try the javascript one.

Comment: I did, neither seem to apply to it.

Comment: I just tried the javascript, it seems to be working on the site. 
`$('#welcomeDiv').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

```
if ($has_results) {
   echo ...
} else {
   // do nothing
}
```

put an if() test on the relevant section, and DON'T echo something when you don't want it to be echoed.